# Pronounciation of final -k in Azeri

Tags: resource-request, pronunciation

So I read that, in Azeri, K can either be pronounced as [c] (in Azeri words) but also [k] (in loanwords). However, in the word "çörək", it turns out that the final -k can either be pronounced as [k], [t͡ʃ] or [j] (as can be seen here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7%C3%B6r%C9%99k#Azerbaijani). Is there some dialectical variation of the letter K in Azeri that it can be pronounced either [c], [k], [t͡ʃ] or [j] at the end of words?

Answer (score 0):

> k – (voiceless palatal stop, aspirated) This letter is pronounced like
> the k in keep but, as with g, also has an added “y” sound, like the
> beginning of the word cute. Be sure to combine this “y” sound with the
> pronunciation of Azerbaijani k.  kim, kəmənd, stəkan, məktəb  **Note:
> **When k is the last letter in a word or syllable, it can optionally be
> pronounced similar to the h in the English word hue (including the “y”
> sound): çiçək** [bolding mine]

[linguistics text](https://minio.la.utexas.edu/webeditor-files/slavic/pdf/azeri.pdf)